# Object comparison help needed

Tags: javascript

I would like to compare the names, if they match, then say we have similar names, else that we have different names. But this code gives output `undefined` while comparing names.

Could someone please help me out to understand/fix this problem?

I want to get following, for example:

> We have different names, Bob and I.

```
function addPersonMethods(obj){
    this.obj = obj;
}

addPersonMethods.prototype.greet = function(str){
    return str + ", my name is "+ this.obj.name;
}

addPersonMethods.prototype.nameshake = function(othername){
    this.othername = othername;
    if (this.obj.name == this.othername){
         console.log("We have the same name ," + this.obj.name + " and I! ");
    }
    else
         console.log("We have different names ," + this.obj.name + " and I.");
}

var bob_def =  { name: 'Bob', age: 21 };
var eve_def =  { name: 'Eve', age: 21 };

var bob = new addPersonMethods(bob_def);
var eve = new addPersonMethods(eve_def);
var another_bob = new addPersonMethods({name:'Bob', age: 40});

console.log(bob.greet("Hi all"));
console.log(eve.greet("Hello"));
console.log(another_bob.greet("Hey"));

console.log(bob.nameshake(eve));
```

Comment: When I try your example, I get "We have different names, Bob and I". That's what you say you want to get. Please fix the question to describe the real problem.

Comment: Sorry my question was unclear.I wanted to check if the names matches then i wanted to print we have same names else we have different. @Barmar

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, but you don't explain it well in the question. Can you fix it to use an example where it gives the wrong result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `nameshake()` method expects a `string` (the name), but you're passing an object, so the comparison will never be `true`.  You want to compare to that object's `.obj.name`.

Second, you're logging the result of `bob.nameshake()`, when the function doesn't actually return anything.

And you're printing your *own* name in the "We have..." statements, when you want to print the other person's.

```js
function addPersonMethods(obj) {
  this.obj = obj;
}

addPersonMethods.prototype.greet = function(str) {
  return str + ", my name is " + this.obj.name;
}

addPersonMethods.prototype.nameshake = function(otherperson) {
  var othername = otherperson.obj.name;

  if (this.obj.name == othername) {
    console.log("We have the same name, " + othername + " and I! ");
  } 
  else
    console.log("We have different names, " + othername + " and I.");
}


var bob_def = {
  name: 'Bob',
  age: 21
};
var eve_def = {
  name: 'Eve',
  age: 21
};


var bob = new addPersonMethods(bob_def);
var eve = new addPersonMethods(eve_def);
var another_bob = new addPersonMethods({
  name: 'Bob',
  age: 40
});

console.log(bob.greet("Hi all"));
console.log(eve.greet("Hello"));
console.log(another_bob.greet("Hey"));

bob.nameshake(eve);
bob.nameshake(another_bob);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul Roub :)

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing a string (`this.obj.name`) to an object (`othername`). They won't be equal so you will always output that they have different names. The return value of any function by default is `undefined` unless you specify otherwise, so that's why your output is tailed by `undefined`.

Either pass in `eve.obj.name` to the function, or extract that value inside the function so you can compare properly.